Show that the product of two symmetric unimodal polynomials is also symmetric unimodal
Problem statement: Let $F(q)$ and $G(q)$ be symmetric unimodal polynomials with nonnegative real coefficients. Show that $F(q)G(q)$ is also symmetric (easy) and unimodal (harder).
Note that "symmetric" is used in this context to mean that for $P(q) = p_0 + p_1 q + \dots + p_n q^n$, a polynomial of degree $n$, we have $p_i = p_{n - i}$, for $0 \leq i \leq n$, and unimodal to mean that there exists some $j$ such that $$p_0 \leq p_1 \leq \dots \leq p_{j - 1} \leq p_j \geq p_{j + 1} \geq \dots \geq p_{n - 1} \geq p_n.$$
What I tried is to expand $$F(q)G(q) = \sum_{i = 0}^{m + n} \left( \sum_{j = 0}^n f_j g_{i - j} \right) q^i = \sum_{i = 0}^{m + n} \left( \sum_{j = 0}^n f_j g_{m + n - i - j} \right) q^{m + n - i},$$ but it didn't quite work as that just reduces the problem to showing that $$\left( \sum_{j = 0}^n f_j g_{i - j} \right) = \left( \sum_{j = 0}^n f_j g_{m + n - i - j} \right) = \left( \sum_{j = 0}^n f_j g_{i + j - n} \right),$$ which I am unable to do.

It is better if we write
$$
F(q)G(q) = \sum_{i=0}^{n+m} c_i q^{i}
$$
with
$$
c_i = \sum_{j+k=i}f_jg_k.
$$
Then we have
$$
c_{n+m-i} = \sum_{j+k=n+m-i}f_jg_k = \sum_{(n-j)+(m-k)=i} f_{n-j}g_{m-k}
$$
and renaming $n-j\mapsto j$ and $m-k\mapsto k$ we obtain
$$
c_{n+m-i} = \sum_{j+k=i} f_j g_k = c_i.
$$
The next is not a complete solution, but is too long for a comment:
Now, to see unimodality define a Laurent polynomial $F_L(q)$ associated to a Polynomial $F(q)$ by
$$
F_L(q) = q^{-\deg F(q)} F(q^2).
$$
Then we can write, under the symmetry hypothesis
$$
F_L(q) = \sum_{i=0}^{n/2} a_i'(q^{-2i}+q^{2i})
$$
for some appropriate $a_i'$ (you can figure out, by a term by term comparison, which must be the value of $a_i'$) if $n=\deg F(q)$ is even, and
$$
F_L(q) = \sum_{i=0}^{(n-1)/2} a_i'(q^{-2i-1}+q^{2i+1})
$$
for some $a_i'$, if $n=\deg F(q)$ is odd. Note that $(GF)_L=F_L G_L$ and that we can recover $F$ from $F_L$ (this you can verify easily).
Here is the reason for considering this Laurent polynomials: The Laurent polynomials of the form $F_L(q)$ for some $F$, with nonnegative integer coefficients, are precisely the characters for finite dimensional representations of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ with the property that the $h$-eigenvalues are all of the same parity, $h$ being the matrix
$$
h = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
If $F_L$ is the character of a representation $V$ and $G_L$ is the character of a representation $W$, then $F_LG_L=(FG)_L$ is the character of $V\otimes W$. Thus by the unimodal property of characters, we obtain the unimodality property of $FG$ (modulo some easy details) (in the case of polynomials with integer coefficients).
I don't know if you are familiar with the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, but for now is the only way I can think about this. Sure some one can provide a more elementary proof.
If you are interested in understanding the details of the solution I have just sketched, I strongly recommend you to see Daniel Litt's presentation of the unimodality of graphs, using again the representation theory of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ here, or his detailed notes here.
